# How to verify Google signin (via Firebase) idToken in nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebase-admin

Trying to verify idToken of a user signed in via firebase authentication (Google signin) in nodejs server. Server throws `Firebase ID token has invalid signature`.

Tried verifying with `firebase-admin` as well as `jsonwebtoken` with public key from the url: `https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com`. Both methods work perfect for users signed in with a password, but throws 'Invalid Signature' in case of a user signed in via google.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Do I need to verify with `google-auth-library` instead?

Code:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(require("../../serviceAccount")), // file received from firebase project settings page
  databaseURL: "as mentioned in the firebase project settings page",
});

// Some code here

var token = "token received from client side";
var decoded = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
```

**PS:**

- All client side features (after signing in) are working fine.
- Everything else on the backend is working fine.
- Decoding the token in both cases gives expected JSON.
- For test run, token is being `forceRefresh`ed everytime before calling the API.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are initializing the Admin SDK in the backend? and you are using the service account downloaded from Firebase [project settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have edited my question to add the code you asked for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP here,**

I am dumb.

I was using the `print()` function of flutter to log the token and call the API myself. Didn't know Flutter's print function has an output character limit. Login using password gives smaller tokens thus the whole token was logged. But Google sign in gives a longer token, longer than the output character limit of print.

**Solution** : Use log function from `'dart:developer'` package.

```
import 'dart:developer';

// 

log(await _auth.idToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");

const client = new OAuth2Client(googleClient[process.env.ENV])
let token = 123456789011-crhch2kuum79bk0qr3usa39f7b9chikc.apps.googleusercontent.com

async function googleLoginVerify(token) {
  try {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: googleClient[process.env.ENV], 
    });
      const payLoad = ticket.getPayload();

    return {
      success: true,
      data: payLoad,
    };

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return {
      success: false,
      message: err.message,
    };
  }
}
```